# Is it possible to write a constraint to exclude a type?

Tags: function, go, generics, interface, constraints

```
type NonString interface {
    // ???
}

func MyFunc[T NonString](v T) T {
    return v
}

func main() {
    MyFunc(1)          // OK
    MyFunc(false)      // OK
    MyFunc([]string{}) // OK

    MyFunc("hi, boy!") // I hope a comiler error occurs here!  
}
```

What I want is decribed in the comments of the code above.

**Is it possible in golang?**

---

***Original Scenario***

I have two functions as follows:

```
func Any2String(v any) string {        
    return fmt.Sprint(v) // Slow version
}

func Integer2String[N Integer](v N) string {
    return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10) // Fast version
}
```

`Any2String(v)` can convert any `v` to a string. However, if `v` is an integer, `Integer2String(v)` is much more faster.

So, I want the compiler to **PREVENT** me from calling `Any2String(v)` when the faster `Integer2String(v)` is applicable.

Comment: This is not possible. What would be the use case for this?

Comment: This is not possible in go. Some languages support template specialization but not go

Comment: Why don't you just have Any2String call Integer2String in that case? Or do a type assertion inline.

Comment: @JonathanHall type assertion has runtime cost of reflection, so I want to avoid it.

Comment: No, type assertions avoid the cost of reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Constraint type sets cannot be expressed as set subtraction.

It is possible to define constraints that can't be satisfied by any type, for example:

```
type NotSatisfiable interface {
    int
    foo()
}
```

This constraint mandates a type that is exactly `int` and that has a method `foo()`. Since you can't define methods on predeclared types, it's not possible to satisfy this constraint.

However you can't define a constraint like "any-minus-int" or "any-plus-NotSatisfiable".

If you have a function that works exactly the same for any type except a discrete number of types, just use a type switch:

```
func ToString(v any) string {
    switch t := v.(type) {
    case int:
        return Integer2String(t)
    default:
        return Any2String(t)
    }
}
```

You don't even need generics, because a regular argument of type `any` works just fine.